# create entity for given relation one to one relationship, primary key of one table is foreign key of another table

Tags: hibernate

[image: hierarchy]

SEND ME HOE TO CREATE ENTITIES FOR THIS RELATION USING HIBERNATE JPA ANNOTATIONS

Comment: Flagged as rude or abusive. Please read [ask] and consider [edit]ing your question.

Comment: @xenteros just edit or vote to close in cases like this.

Comment: @ChrisF "SEND ME HOE TO CREATE ENTITIES FOR THIS RELATION USING HIBERNATE JPA ANNOTATIONS" is definitely rude.

Answer (score 0):

this is a OneToOne Mapping between a user and his profile

```
@Entity
public class User {

@Id
private int id;
private String name;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Profile profile;

}
```

profile Entity

```
@Entity
public class Profil{

    @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "foreign", 
    parameters = @Parameter(name = "property", value = "user"))
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
    private int id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private User user;

}
```